# issue with the output of dir->read() in php

Tags: php

inside ajax folder, there are files:
json.php, load.php, script.php

main.php

```
<?php
$dir = dir("ajax");
while (($file = $dir->read()) !== false)
{
echo "filename: " . $file . "<br />";
}

$dir->close();
```

It show:

```
filename: .
filename: ..
filename: json.php
filename: load.php
filename: script.php
```

Question:
In the result, what does the first two items mean? `.` `..` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are the `current (.)` and `parent (..)` directories.

You can get rid of them in following way:

`$result = array_diff($result, array('..', '.'));`

Answer (score 0):

`.` and `..` are "directories" which equate to the current directory, and parent directory, respectively.

for example, if you are in the ajax folder, `json.php` can also be accessed with `./json.php`.

on the other hand, `../json.php` will look for the file in the parent folder (same directory as the `ajax` folder).

Answer (score 0):

`Single dot: .` This represents current directory.

`Double dot: ..` This represents parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

`.` is current folder.
`..` is parent folder. Any folders on window and linux have two this.

If you want to read some type of file, you can use `glob` function of php.

`$files = glob($dirpath.'/*.php');`